# Testing a URI with local image

Tags: java, spring, junit

Below method takes a url which points to an image and returns the input stream:

```
public InputStream getIs(URI uri) {
  // some implementation...
}
```

To unit test this I plan to use a url I selected via a Google search: https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg" therefore create a URI using:

```
new URI("https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg")
```

But this seems bad practice. **Should I add an image to the `test/resources` folder of the `Maven` project and read the image from there?** If I do this then the URI is no longer valid as

```
new URI("classpath:testimage.jpg")
```

throws exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException:
  I/O error on GET request for "classpath:testimage.jpg":
  URI does not specify a valid host name: classpath:testimage.jpg;
  nested exception is org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException:
  URI does not specify a valid host name: classpath:testimage.jpg
```

Comment: Why did you write your own method to do this instead of using one of several common libraries?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I'm working with a legacy code base. But even if I could use a library method to convert a URI to an inputStream I still would require a mechanism to test the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best practice for unit tests is to use a resource file.
Try this solution to provide correct `URI` value for your `getIs()` method:

```
URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image.jpg");
URI uri = res.toURI();
```